# Changing json file format to .spacy for custom NER tagging

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I want to create a custom tag for my project. To get help on this topic I went through [Using spaCy 3.0 to build a custom NER model](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-spacy-3-0-to-build-a-custom-ner-model-c9256bea098) this tutorial. The contain of the JSON file

```
[{"text": "The F15 aircraft uses a lot of fuel", "entities": [4, 7, "aircraft"]},
 {"text":"did you see the F16 landing?", "entities": [16, 19, "aircraft"]},
 {"text":"how many missiles can a F35 carry", "entities": [24, 27, "aircraft"]},
 {"text":"is the F15 outdated", "entities": [7, 10, "aircraft"]},
 {"text":"does the US still train pilots to dog fight?","entities": [0, 0, "aircraft"]},
 {"text":"how long does it take to train a F16 pilot","entities": [33, 36, "aircraft"]}]
```

However, this is an old file format. We need to build a custom NER model in Spacy v3.1. So there is a code block in the tutorial that can change the .json format to the .spacy format.

The following is the code block

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import DocBin

nlp = spacy.blank("en") # load a new spacy model
db = DocBin() # create a DocBin object

for text, annot in tqdm(TRAIN_DATA): # data in previous format
    doc = nlp.make_doc(text) # create doc object from text
    ents = []
    for start, end, label in annot["entities"]: # add character indexes
        span = doc.char_span(start, end, label=label, alignment_mode="contract")
        if span is None:
            print("Skipping entity")
        else:
            ents.append(span)
    doc.ents = ents # label the text with the ents
    db.add(doc)
```

When I ran this code I received errors.

[image]

How can I overcome the error?